# Is it possible to have a model field set to subtract sum of values from many table

Tags: python, django, database

I'm creating a crypto-currency app. I have a table called Transaction, which can have 0 or many sales stored on Sale Table. Is it possible to set up a field on the Transaction model "coins_remaining" that will be equal to (amount - sum(amount_sold) from sale table).

Transaction model below

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    currency = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    amount = models.IntegerField()
    total_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_purchased = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin = self.total_price / self.amount
        super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Sale table below

```
class Sale(models.Model):
    amount_sold = models.IntegerField()
    total_price_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    date_sold = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    note = models.TextField(default="")
    transaction = models.ForeignKey(Transaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_per_coin_sold = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.amount_per_coin_sold = self.total_price_sold / self.amount_sold
        super(Sale, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define a property on transaction that does it:

```
@property
def coins_remaining(self):
    return self.amount - sum(self.sales.all().values_list('amount_sold', flat=True))
```

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I have tried this and i am getting the error that "'Transaction' object has no attribute 'sales'. Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: @Philip well that's weird, add a `related_name="sales"` on the transaction ForeignKey and perform a makemigrations and migrate... though it should have worked by default.

Answer (score 0):

you can create the transaction table as a DataFrame, take the sum of the "amount_sold" column then substract it from the amount

```
t = Transaction()
s = Sale()

s.transactions = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3,4,5], 'amount_sold': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})

coins_remaining = t.amount - s.transactions['amount_sold'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks Quy. I don't understand where I would insert this code. Could you show me how I could integrate it with my code please.